# Importing large integers from a mixed datatype file with numpy genfromtxt

Tags: python, file-io, types, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a file with the format:

```
1    2.5264    24106644528  astring
```

I would like to import the data. I am using:

```
>>> numpy.genfromtxt('myfile.dat',dtype=None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    numpy.genfromtxt('myfile.dat',skip_header=27,dtype=None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1691, in genfromtxt
    output = np.array(data, dtype=ddtype)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I checked the maximum integer on my (32-bit) system:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
2147483647
```

Is there a way to increase the integer limit? Or can I get around my import problem  another way (without putting '.0' after all of the ints in file)?

Comment: Maybe check out the 'converters' argument of genfromtxt? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#tweaking-the-conversion

Comment: So the converter would probably try to match 11 integers in a row and convert that to a float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realised I can do this:

```
>>> numpy.genfromtxt('myfile.dat',dtype=['i4','f8','f8','a14'])

array((1, 2.5264, 24106644528.0, 'astring'), 
  dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S14')])
```

Comment: Haha that seems easier

Comment: If you are on a 32-bit system, won't 'f8' (np.float64), revert to 'f4' (np.float32)? If that is the case, that above will cause you to lose precision.

Comment: @bdforbes your idea is intriguing -  although it seems to require use of `lambda`, which I'm not familiar with...

Comment: `lambda` is pretty straight forward but in any case your solution is much better, provided you know how the data is organised in your file, which obviously you do